# arXiv identifier near the end of month

Tags: arxiv, preprint, deadlines, online-publication

If one submit a paper (today) on Oct 30th at 20:00:01 GMT (16:00:01 EDT) on arXiv, which announces on Nov 1st 00:00:00 GMT, **is the identifier 1311.xxxx or 1310.xxxx?**

What is the general policy of arXiv to have 1311.xxxx or 1310.xxxx when submitting a paper near the end of Oct? When is the cutline between the twos?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0079

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Why does it matter?

Answer (score 3):

The information on arXiv's [help pages](http://arxiv.org/help/submit) implies that the identifier is based on the submission date, see e.g.:

> Submissions are assigned identifiers and appear in the listings in order based on the submission time (the last time the "Submit" button was selected at the end of the submission process). An edit and subsequent "Submit" will reset this time and thus change position in the listings. Edits are permitted between 16:00 and the 20:00 announcement time. However, doing this will remove the submission from that day's announcements and delay it until the next day.

If so, a manuscript submitted today should get the identifier **1310.xxxx**. This also seems to fit with a couple of random papers I looked at, e.g. [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.7382) (Submitted 27/09-2013, announced 01/10-2013).

However, note that arXiv seems to use 20:00 GMT as the daily deadline for submission (see e.g. [here](http://arxiv.org/localtime)), so submissions made after that are transferred to the next date.

Comment: Thanks, but, are you sure??? Like this one: http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0050, from 1310.0001-1310.0050, they all submitted in the end of Sept, but their numbers are 1310.xxxx. Can you explain it?

Comment: @Idear I only know what I have read on their help pages, and I'm not affiliated with arXiv. However, in that particular case I suspect that the reason is that the paper was submitted after 20:00. See quote above and [here](http://arxiv.org/localtime) - "*...there is roughly 1/4 hour remaining until the next deadline (Wed 30 Oct 13 20:00:00 GMT).*".